# Create a full directory structure/skeleton through the terminal - expressJS/nodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express, directory

I have seen some tips on the internet on how to create the full directory structure for a node project with a command line with expressJS.
Here are some examples:

`express express-skeleton` << http://quickleft.com/blog/getting-started-with-express-in-node

`./node_modules/.bin/express -t ejs` << http://naholyr.fr/2011/08/ecrire-service-rest-nodejs-express-partie-1/

`--l` << http://www.techrepublic.com/article/build-nodejs-web-applications-with-express/

But none of those work for me. I have install express and update it to have it globally installed with `npm update express -g` but my terminal doesn't even recognize the command line express.

How can I build a web app skeleton easily with the command line? Thanks a lot

**EDIT:** when running the `npm install -g express` command line, I get this error message:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/arnauddrizard/Documents/Dev/RestAPI
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/arnauddrizard/Documents/Dev/RestAPI/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm unable to create folder inside your application folder.
Give sufficient permissons to your folder, I hope that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

What output do you get when you run npm install -g express? The problem is most likely that npm install -g is not installing to somewhere that's in your PATH.